# Rename multiple files in HDFS directory dynamically

Tags: linux, hdfs

I have a directory in `HDFS` that contains many files like below.

```
_SUCCESS
part-00000
part-00001
part-00002
part-00003
part-00004
part-00005
part-00006
```

Now I want to rename the files that start with `part-number` to `test-number.csv`

I have done like below

```
hdfs dfs -mv /user/xxx/dir/part-00000 /user/xxx/dir/test-00000.csv
```

and so on

I am able to get what I want

Is there a way to do this dynamically

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions that have been asked and answered so many times you have to make an effort to avoid finding an answer. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a for loop in bash:

```
for n in {0..6} ; do
    long=$(printf %05d "$n")
    hdfs dfs -mv /user/xxx/dir/part-"$long" /user/xxx/dir/test-"$long".csv
done
```

I used `printf` to format the number.

Comment: You asnwer works perfect. Just a small doubt what If I have more than 20 files `{0..6}` here can we have a dynamic number

Comment: You can use `for n in $(seq 0 $max) ; do`, or you can iterate over the files - but I don't know hdfs enough to know the exact commands.